# Social distancing in the mosque

Tags: salat, masjid

What to do when the authority recommends (case1) or obliges (case2) social distancing (distance between people in safs) but the imam doesn't want to follow that?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is hardly about Islam than about local law and order

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "what to do" is highly opinion-based and any proper answer would require far more information than you've provided; please note that we are *not* a fatwa site.

Answer (score 1):

In this medical situation you have to listen doctors and authorities as general muftis don't have DNA doctors degree, neither they are some high level DNA researchers, so how can one judge something when they know nothing about it.

Answer (score 0):

Imam should follow it as Prophet command us to
Hadith

حَدَّثَنَا الْقَعْنَبِيُّ، عَنْ مَالِكٍ، عَنْ نَافِعٍ، أَنَّ ابْنَ عُمَرَ، - يَعْنِي أَذَّنَ بِالصَّلاَةِ فِي لَيْلَةٍ ذَاتِ بَرْدٍ وَرِيحٍ - فَقَالَ أَلاَ صَلُّوا فِي الرِّحَالِ ثُمَّ قَالَ إِنَّ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم كَانَ يَأْمُرُ الْمُؤَذِّنَ إِذَا كَانَتْ لَيْلَةٌ بَارِدَةٌ أَوْ ذَاتُ مَطَرٍ يَقُولُ أَلاَ صَلُّوا فِي الرِّحَالِ ‏.‏

Nafi said:

Ibn "Umar made the call to prayer on a cold and windy night. He then said: "Lo! Pray in the dwellings. "Afterwards he said: Whenever there was a cold or rainy day night, the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) used to command the mu'adhdin to announce: "Lo! Pray in the dwellings."

Sahih (Al-Albani)

Sunan Abi Dawud 1063
In-book : Book 2, Hadith 674
English translation : Book 2, Hadith 1058
Abu Dawood
When there was just rain ...prophet command the muslim to pray in their in oen homes.so in today circumstances we can pray in home in the light of this hadith.
If imam wants to have prayer in congeration but with gap of 6 m which is not acceptable.
Hadith

حَدَّثَنَا عَلِيُّ بْنُ مُحَمَّدٍ، حَدَّثَنَا وَكِيعٌ، حَدَّثَنَا الأَعْمَشُ، عَنِ الْمُسَيَّبِ بْنِ رَافِعٍ، عَنْ تَمِيمِ بْنِ طَرَفَةَ، عَنْ جَابِرِ بْنِ سَمُرَةَ السُّوَائِيِّ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم ـ ‏‏ أَلاَ تَصُفُّونَ كَمَا تَصُفُّ الْمَلاَئِكَةُ عِنْدَ رَبِّهَا ‏"‏ ‏.‏ قَالَ قُلْنَا وَكَيْفَ تَصُفُّ الْمَلاَئِكَةُ عِنْدَ رَبِّهَا قَالَ ‏"‏ يُتِمُّونَ الصُّفُوفَ الأُوَلَ وَيَتَرَاصُّونَ فِي الصَّفِّ ‏"‏ ‏.‏"

It was narrated that Jabir bin Samurah As-Suwa'i said:

"The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "Will you not form your rows as the angels form their rows before their Lord?' We said: "How do the angels form their rows before their Lord?' He said: "They complete the first row and they stand close of one another in the line (leaving no gaps between one another).'"

English : Vol. 1, Book 5, Hadith 992
Arabic : Book 5, Hadith 1045
Sunan Ibn Majah
They should not be any gap so imam have to follow prophet hadith.

Comment: i don't know about every place mosque but Imams usually ask for 3 feet to 6 feet not 6 meter as you mentioned above.